# Is it possible to use cut on a collection of datetimes?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Is it possible to use `pandas.cut` to make bins out of `datetime` stamps?

The following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

contenttext = """Time,Bid
2014-03-05 21:56:05:924300,1.37275
2014-03-05 21:56:05:924351,1.37272
2014-03-05 21:56:06:421906,1.37275
2014-03-05 21:56:06:421950,1.37272
2014-03-05 21:56:06:920539,1.37275
2014-03-05 21:56:06:920580,1.37272
2014-03-05 21:56:09:071981,1.37275
2014-03-05 21:56:09:072019,1.37272"""

content = StringIO.StringIO(contenttext)
df = pd.read_csv(content, header=0)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

pd.cut(df['Time'], 5)
```

Throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f5387a84c335> in <module>()
     16 df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
     17 
---> 18 pd.cut(df['Time'], 5)

/home/???????/sites/varsite/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/tile.pyc in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest)
     80         else:
     81             rng = (nanops.nanmin(x), nanops.nanmax(x))
---> 82         mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in rng]
     83 
     84         if mn == mx:  # adjust end points before binning

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'float'
```

Comment: you'd better store an epoch time instead of a datetime object and only convert it when you want to show it to the user

Comment: you can try `pd.cut(df.Time.map( lambda x: x.value ), 5)`; you will also have `pd.Timestamp(df.Time[i].value) == df.Time[i]` for all `i`

Comment: this is not hard to implement; would u pls post on github as an issue with an example of input and output

Comment: The requested URL /svn/trunk/data/new/eur-fix.csv was not found on this server.

Comment: Sorry for that.  Fixed up above with hard-coded data.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but for any future visitors, I think this is a clearer way to calculate float timedeltas to use cut on:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Get Days Since Date
today = dt.date.today()
df['days ago'] = (today - df['time']).dt.days

# Get Seconds Since Datetime
now = dt.datetime.now()
df['seconds ago'] = (now - df['time']).dt.seconds

# Minutes Since Datetime
# (no dt.minutes attribute, so we use seconds/60)
now = dt.datetime.now()
df['minutes ago'] = (now - df['times']).dt.seconds/60
```

All of these columns are now float values that we can use `pd.cut()` on

Answer (score 2):

Here is my work-around. You might need to change the code slightly to suit your precision needs. I use date as an example below:

```
# map dates to timedelta
today=dt.date.today() 

# x below is a timedelta,
# use x.value below if you need more precision
df['days']=map(lambda x : x.days, df.Time - today)

pd.cut(df.days, bins=5)
```

Effectively you turn `datetime` or `date` into a numerical distance measure, then cut/qcut it.