# Pandas Time Series division

Tags: python, pandas

I've a table containing 7 features. Last of them is a timestamp. I just want to divide that time series data into equal slots of 10 minutes each. So I can check which instance falls in which slot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch :)

Comment: `pandas.cut()` can help you, although apparently you can't use it directly on a datetime. but if you create a column of `minutes_since_start`, then you can use `pandas.cut()` on `minutes_since_start` to get your 10-minute groupings.

Comment: here's an example of someone doing that, but with days instead of minutes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286930/is-it-possible-to-use-cut-on-a-collection-of-datetimes

Comment: What do you mean by "divide"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Create reproduceable example data 
# (in the future, it's better if you do this in your question)
first_timestamp = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2011 00:00')

timestamps = pd.date_range(first_timestamp, periods=100, freq='1Min')
other_data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100,))

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': timestamps,
                   'other_data': other_data})

# Create a timedelta of minutes since first timestamp
# timedeltas have attributes for days and seconds, but not minutes.
df['minutes_since_start'] = (df['timestamp'] - first_timestamp).dt.seconds / 60

# Create groups
df['timestamp group'] = pd.cut(df['minutes_since_start'], bins=range(0,101, 10),include_lowest=True)

# first 3 entries
df.head(5)
```

output:

```
   other_data           timestamp  minutes_since_start timestamp group
0           8 2011-01-01 00:00:00                  0.0         [0, 10]
1           5 2011-01-01 00:01:00                  1.0         [0, 10]
2           7 2011-01-01 00:02:00                  2.0         [0, 10]
```

get data from arbitrary timestamp group, e.g. 70-80 minutes after start

```
df[df['timestamp group'] == '(70, 80]']
```

output:

```
    other_data           timestamp  minutes_since_start timestamp group
71           1 2011-01-01 01:11:00                 71.0        (70, 80]
72           8 2011-01-01 01:12:00                 72.0        (70, 80]
73           3 2011-01-01 01:13:00                 73.0        (70, 80]
74           0 2011-01-01 01:14:00                 74.0        (70, 80]
75           8 2011-01-01 01:15:00                 75.0        (70, 80]
76           8 2011-01-01 01:16:00                 76.0        (70, 80]
77           0 2011-01-01 01:17:00                 77.0        (70, 80]
78           6 2011-01-01 01:18:00                 78.0        (70, 80]
79           0 2011-01-01 01:19:00                 79.0        (70, 80]
80           5 2011-01-01 01:20:00                 80.0        (70, 80]
```